# Getting sum as Nan after execution of for loop

Tags: c

I am using series expansion to approximate value of sin up to a finite no. Of for loop iterations. I have used a j loop to calculate value of factorial of 2i+1.please help if I have made a mistake somewhere.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Enter the value of angle:" );
    double ag, rad, sum = 0;
    scanf("%lf", &ag);
    rad = 3.14159 * ag / 180.0;
    int i, j, frac = 1;
    for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= 2*i+1; j++)                   
            frac *= j;
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            sum += pow(rad, 2*i+1) / frac;
        else
            sum += (-pow(rad, 2*i+1) / frac);
    }
    printf("Required sum=%f", sum);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could format the code to make it a little more readable.

Comment: you can actually improve your ident

Comment: Avoid signed integer overflow!

Comment: Using `3.14159` for PI is ludicrous! you lose a lot of precision before uou even start computing.  No need to loop 101 times.  Use `M_PI` from `<math.h>` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for `Nan` is at some time in loop `frac` goes to `0` because of integer overflow. Dividing `sum` by `0` make it `Nan`.

Just tested your program

```
# include<stdio.h>
# include<math.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter the value of angle:" );
    double ag,rad,sum=0;
    scanf("%lf",&ag);
    rad=3.14159*ag/180.0;
    printf("%f\n", rad);
    int i,j,frac=1;
    for(i=0;i<=100;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=2*i+1;j++)
            frac*=j;
        if(i%2==0)
        {   
             sum+=pow(rad,2*i+1)/frac; 
             printf("if: %f, %d\n", sum, frac);
        }
        else
        {
             sum+=(-pow(rad,2*i+1)/frac);  
             printf("else: %f, %d\n", sum, frac);
        }
    }
    printf("Required sum=%f\n",sum);
    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the value of angle:30
0.523598
if: 0.523598, 1
else: 0.499674, 6
if: 0.499728, 720
else: 0.499728, 3628800
if: 0.499728, -1736015872
else: 0.499728, -2004877312
if: inf, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
else: nan, 0
if: nan, 0
Required sum=nan
```

Comment: No. Adding something to infinity generally yields infinity, too.

Comment: `fract` is not likely to become `0` , IMHO.

Comment: @ameyCU; It will actually.

Comment: @ameyCU: It depends on how signed integer overflow is handled, but because every other term in the factorial will contribute at least one factor of 2, you get a number that is divisible by 2^32 eventually, which might be treated as zero.

Comment: @MOehm Thanks for your help . I get to understand that :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are trying to do is calculate the series expansion of *sin(x)*.

There doesn't seem to be MathJax markup on this site, so let's just say this is the sum from `k=0` to infinity of each term as follows (with alternating sign):

```
x^(2k+1) / (2k+1)!
```

The problem here is that as `k` gets large, `x^(2k+1)` gets large very quickly, and `(2k+1)!` gets even larger very quickly. So the term will converge to zero, and the sum also converges, but calculating the top and the bottom of the term individually will end up with very large numbers. This means that the factorial term (which grows the fastest) will eventually not fit in the `double` variable you have provided, resulting in an error. The top of the equation will do the same in due course as well. I suspect technically the reason for `NaN` is that you are dividing by a term that has overflowed. Also note that you are holding `frac` as an integer (not a double); this will overflow.

You would be better observing that each term can be calculated from the next by multiplying by `x^2` and dividing by `2k(2k+1)` (or something like that - I'm doing the maths in my head). That way you need only calculate one term in full, and you won't get large numbers. This also has the advantage that you don't need to calculate the factorial, and you don't need to use the `pow()` function - just basic arithmetic operations.

Here's what I mean:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int
main (void)
{
  printf ("Enter the value of angle:");
  double ag, rad, sum = 0.0;
  scanf ("%lf", &ag);
  rad = 3.14159 * ag / 180.0;
  int i;

  /* first term for k = 0 we calculate manually. The first term */
  /* is x^1 / 1! which is just x */
  double term = rad;
  sum += term;

  for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
      /* each successive term has an extra 2 powers of x on the */
      /* top, an (2i) and a (2i+1) on the bottom, and changes sign */
      term *= -rad * rad / (2.0 * i) / (2.0 * i + 1.0);
      sum += term;
    }
  printf ("Required sum=%f\n", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a good fix for the `NaN` result, but you must use `M_PI` to compute the precise value.  You should also stop iterating when the increment becomes so small that `sum + term == sum`.

Comment: @chqrlie - sure. I was making the minimum changes to the algorithm to solve the OP's problem, rather than the design the best algorithm for calculating *sin(x)*.

Comment: Thanks a lot,for that fix...I am just learning to code, totally forgot about integer overflow..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in the `scanf`. Try to debug/print out the value of `ag` after the user input. If it is wrong, try to include `<float.h>`.

Comment: Why should including `float.h` help anything?

Answer (score 0):

`frac` will be too big to fit in `int`, and overflow in signed integer arithmetic is *undefined behavior*.

Unfortunately, the factorial `200!` is too big to fit in 64-bit IEEE754 floating point variable, so consider reducing the number of loop or doing the multiplication and division alternatively.

By the way, didn't you forget `frac` at the beginning of each iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Note the `division` operation by `frac` variable - you need to check that `frac` is not `zero` prior to dividing.

```
    if(i%2==0) { 
        if (frac != 0) {
          sum+=pow(rad,2*i+1)/frac;
        } 
    } else {
        if (frac != 0) { 
          sum+=(-pow(rad,2*i+1)/frac);
        } 
    }
```

** DEBUG **

```
   frac | j  | (frac*j)
    1 1 1
    1 1 1
    1 2 2
    2 3 6
    6 1 6
    6 2 12
    12 3 36
    36 4 144
    ...
    822935552 3 -1826160640
    -1826160640 4 1285292032
    1285292032 5 2131492864
    2131492864 6 -95944704
    -95944704 7 -671612928
    ...
    1476395008 8 -1073741824
    -1073741824 9 -1073741824
    -1073741824 10 -2147483648
    -2147483648 11 -2147483648
    -2147483648 12 0  <======== NOTE HERE - frac becomes zero.
```

UPDATE1 - So - also to correctly answer - the right thing to do - is NOT check for frac whether it's zero (it doesn't hurt though while dividing) but to use the right data types.

UPDATE2 - the intrinsic nature of the algorithm makes it difficult to not get into this problem. Large numbers are involved so either use a construct where you use linked list way of storing Big numbers or break the iterations when you reach `frac = 0` since post that it will always remain `zero`. I tried using `long long` which is `8 bytes` and that too reaches `0`.

Comment: `fract`  has value `fract*j` , there should not be any case where it will be `0`  as both are initialized to `1` .

Comment: @ameyCU Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior and there may be a case that `frac` become 0, but `fract` won't become 0 here because it is not defined.

Comment: @ameyCU: True in theory, but in practice, `frac` may be zero. [34! is a multiple of 2^32](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151214-00/?p=92621) and if on this platform, signed overflow is handled like unsigned overflow, the factorial may get zero. Because the OP forgot to reset `fact` before each calculation, a multiple of 32 is reached earlier.

Comment: Yeah - I notice that. I realize that is what is happening due to integer truncation. I will update the answer with what I notice on debug.

Comment: @ManojAwasthi: `frac` indeed may become zero at some point and of course stay null for the rest of the computation.  This explains the `NaN` result because sum will be incremented by one infinity and then incremented with the opposite infinity, producing a `NaN` (`Inf - Inf -> NaN`).  Once `sum` is `NaN`, it will stay so for all subsequent incrementations.